# How can I return a value from a class object?

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

Is it possible to have a class object return a true/false value, so I can do something like this:

```
MyClass a;
...
if (a)
    do_something();
```

I can accomplish (almost) what I want by overloading the ! operator:

```
class MyClass {
    ...
    bool operator!() const { return !some_condition; };
    ...
}

main()
    MyClass a;
    ...
    if (!a)
        do_something_different();
```

but I haven't found a way to overload what would be the "empty" operator. Of course, using the == operator to check for true/false is also possible, and is in fact what I have been doing so far.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Overload the void * cast operator:

```
operator void * () const { return some_condition; };
```

this is how streams work, allowing you to say:

```
if ( cin ) {
   // stream is OK
}
```

The use of void * rather than bool prevents the cast being used by mistake in some contexts, such as arithmetic, where it would not be desirable. Unless, you want to use it in those contexts, of course.

Comment: The `bool` operator is more specific than the `void *` one. Could you please show an example of mistake involving cast to bool?

Comment: Thanks. This works just fine, except I had to cast some_condition into (void*). However, everyone else here suggests overloading bool(), which also works just fine and makes the code looks easier to understand :) Could you please give an example of where things could go wrong with that solution, so I can better understand the benefits of your suggestion?

Comment: @Dacav I don't know what you men by more specific - a void * cannot be part of an arithmetic expression so the class cannot be used in the form `a + 1`, which as I suggested may or may not be what the OP wants.

Comment: @Terje See comment above. and I've edited my answer slightly.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: thanks, now I see the problem. I tried to cout something like `static_cast<int>(3 + m)` where m is an instance of a class overloading bool, and the compiler actually accepted it!

Comment: Yes, thanks Neil. That is a very valid point you've made as this solution would catch such mistakes at compile-time. So if no one else comes up with an even better solution or valid counter-arguments within the next day, I'll mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: @Terje Mikal: The safe bool idiom is even better, see (and accept) sbk's answer.

Comment: Adding an implicit cast to `void*` enables `delete a;`.

Comment: @Phillip On g++ you get `warning: deleting 'void*' is undefined`

Answer (score 6):

The obvious solution – providing an implicit conversion to `bool` via `operator bool` – is a bad idea.

That’s why the standard library uses `operator void*` as shown in Neil’s answer.

However, it’s worth pointing out that even this solution has flaws and is therefore no longer considered safe. Unfortunately, coming up with a better solution isn’t trivial …

There’s an article over at Artima that describes the [**safe bool idiom**](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html). For a real library, this is definitely the way to go, since it offers the most robust interface that is hardest to use wrong.

Comment: It is also the most complicated approach. It may be worth asking "do I need to be able to use the class directly where a bool is expected?" May be simpler and saner to just provide a `is_ok` member function, or perhaps overload `operator()` to return a bool and then test `if (a())` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the link, Konrad (and sbk). That was very interesting reading, and certainly something to keep for future reference.

Comment: @jalf: true, this is why I added that “for real libraries …”. The point is, for a library, the benefit to the user *always* outweighs the effort of the implementor. A hard-to-use and easy interface wins, hands down.

Answer (score 5):

Weird, no one has mentioned the [safe bool idiom](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html) so far. All the other solutions described so far have drawbacks (which you might or might not care about), all those approaches are described in the article. In a nutshell, the safe bool idiom goes something like this:

```
  class Testable {
    typedef void (Testable::*bool_type)() const;
    void this_type_does_not_support_comparisons() const {}
  public:
    operator bool_type() const {
      return /* condition here */ ? 
        &Testable::this_type_does_not_support_comparisons  // true value
        : 0; // false value
    }
  };
```

Comment: At least one of the "problems" described in the article, deleting the result of  a void * cast, is a bit dubious. All compilers I use give a at least a warning on this, as it is UB.

Comment: Yes, I'm deleting my suggestion of casting to bool as it's misleadingly flawed.

If you really want it to be treated like a bool in all contexts, then casting to bool is perfect. Casting to void* has its value, but its flaws also. This is the general solution to go for, with casting to bool being the one to go for if it **really** should be treated as a bool in all contexts.

Comment: AFAIK, in C++0x you will be able to mark conversion operators **explicit**, removing the need for a safe bool idiom?

Answer (score -1):

Try overloading the (bool) operator:

```
operator bool() { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Bad idea, and discouraged. See Neil’s answers for details.

Comment: -1 this has unintended side effects, see the Safe Bool Idiom for an alternative solution.